# lxml errors with scraping website html for text data. Tried several iterations

Tags: python, html, lxml

I'm trying to get the congress house members text attributes from the https://www.congress.gov/members website. I'm very new at this. I followed a tutorial on youtube and think I am very close.

Here is a snippet of the html info I am trying to get. Text shown in bold.

[image: Picture of the HTML from website]

Here is my syntax that I think gets me the closest (using python 2.7 - work constraints) :

```
import requests, lxml
import lxml.html
#from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = requests.get('https://www.congress.gov/members?q=%7B%22congress%22%3A%22117%22%2C%22chamber%22%3A%22Senate%22%7D')
doc = lxml.html.fromstring(html.content)

house = doc.xpath('//div[@id="houseMemberNavigator"]')[0]

print(house)#got printed element div

members = house.xpath('.//select[@id="members-representatives"]/text()')
#returns ['\n        ', '                        ']

print(members)
```

I'm sure it's my syntax but have not been able to solve....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `BeautifulSoup`

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')
[data.text for data in soup.find(id='members-representatives').select('option[value]')]

['Find a Representative',
 'Adams, Alma S. [D-NC-12]',
 'Aderholt, Robert B. [R-AL-4]',
 'Aguilar, Pete [D-CA-31]',
 'Allen, Rick W. [R-GA-12]',
 'Allred, Colin Z. [D-TX-32]',
 'Amodei, Mark E. [R-NV-2]',
 'Armstrong, Kelly [R-ND]',
 'Arrington, Jodey C. [R-TX-19]',
 'Auchincloss, Jake [D-MA-4]',
 'Axne, Cynthia [D-IA-3]',
 'Babin, Brian [R-TX-36]',
  ...]
```

Comment: NICE, couldn't have been more simple. I tried messing around with beautiful soup & kept getting the entire html text so tried something else. My mistake was soup = BeautifulSoup(html, lxml). Just needed the .text. Thank you!!!